# Can't execute javac or other command line applications in Java using ProcessBuilder under Windows 7

Tags: java, executable, javac, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute javac from Java using ProcessBuilder but i get no output and nothing happens.  I tried reading the input stream (as there is a bug where the process hangs if i don't read it) but still no results.  I originally passed all required parameters to javac but it was not working, so i simplified it down to just javac (which should print the help message).

i tried running
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  /c C:\\"Program Files\"\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javac.exe"
"C:\\"Program Files\"\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javac.exe"
and surrounding the entire path to javac with double quotes but still nothing.

I get the error

Cannot run program "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe  /c C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javac.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

but if i copy the command and run it from the command line it works fine.

I am aware of using the JavaCompiler class to compile my files but i would prefer to get this problem fixed first as i can't run any dos application or .bat file from Java.  I can run GUI programs like notepad.exe fine though.

```
String[]  commands = new String[]{
             "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe  /c C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe"
          };

  logger.log(Level.INFO, "About to run javac with the command below:");
  String commandToOutput = "";
  for (String command : commands) {
     commandToOutput += command + " ";
  }
  logger.log(Level.INFO, commandToOutput);



  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
  Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

Edit 2

```
String[] commands = new String[]{
         "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe", "-d", "\"" + tempDir + "\"", "-classpath", classpath
      };
```

Edit 3

why is it that the second commands array works but the first does not below.

```
//this gives me CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
      commands = new String[]{
                 "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe"
              };

//this works
      commands = new String[]{
                 "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
                 "/c",
                 "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe",
              };
```

Comment: A bit late, but I don't think this `C:\"Program Files"\Java\...` path looks right. Either put the quotes around the full path, or let them away.

Answer (score 2):

The string array that you pass to ProcessBuilder should contain one argument per array element, not everything in a single big string.

Try this:

```
String[] commands = new String[] 
{
  "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", 
  "/c", 
  "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe"
};
```

Btw: there is no need to call cmd.exe, you can pass javac.exe directly to the ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
   "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe", "\\Path\\To\\MyClass.java"
);
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and now i don't get an error but there is still no output from javac on standard input or error streams.  When i supply the classpath parameters, it produces no compiled files either.

Comment: I had already tried your second suggestion and it yields "Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to compile files. Cannot run program "C:\"Program Files"\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javac.exe": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied". BTW i'm running this through a JUnit test in NetBeans 6.9.1

Comment: Well "access denied" is something completely different and does not stem from the ProcessBuilder call. Most probably you are not giving an output directory for the javac call and thus it's trying to write to c:\Program Files which a regular user cannot do.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought, but i'm running as an administrator and i added the command i'm running to my question.  Temp directory is a directory at the same level as my source code (not in program files) and classpath is the list of java files and jars required to compile.

Comment: Ok part of this was my bad, i had a bug in the thread that was reading the input so i wouldn't see anything.  Once i fixed that your first solution worked, but the second one gives me an "CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied".  Ie. please see edit 3 above.

Comment: I wonder if the quotes around Program Files are correct. Shouldn't they be around the *whole* Path to java.exe?

Answer (score 1):

You have to read from `process.getInputStream()` yourself. As far as I know, processes' output doesn't automatically show on stdout.

Comment: yes i do that.  I didn't show the code to avoid extra complexity but i read all data from the input stream in a separate thread as it comes in.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method of process builder.  Use the single string version, i.e. don't pass a string array, just pass a string.  The string array version is for when you've already already divided up the command into the program, its options, and its the arguments.  As it stands now, its looking for a program executable file called `C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe  /c C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe`.

Alternatively, split your command into the program and arguments in the string array and then you can use the String array version of process builder.

```
String[] = new String[] {
    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "/c",
    "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23\\bin\\javac.exe"
}
```

And

Comment: I tried this and now i don't get an error but there is still no output from javac on standard input or error streams.  When i supply the classpath parameters, it produces no compiled files either.