# Java writing to a file using ProccesBuilder

Tags: java

When i do this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping " + ipText.getText() + " -t -l " + packetSizeText.getText());
            pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(outputFile));
            Process p = pb.start();
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 23 more
```

I really have no idea why it can't find the file it's in the right spot, it exists there is nothing wrong with it.

This is the file: ` private File outputFile = new File("Output.txt");

And yes you can write to the file i did this to test it:

```
System.out.println(outputFile.canWrite());
```

`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute javac or other command line applications in Java using ProcessBuilder under Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985038/cant-execute-javac-or-other-command-line-applications-in-java-using-processbuil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [JavaDoc `ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.lang.String...)), the constructor wants an array of `String` values, where each element in the array is command and parameters

This means that the constructor should look more like...

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
      "ping",
      ipText.getText(), 
      "-t", "-l",
      packetSizeText.getText());
 pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.to(outputFile));
 Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: That makes a nice change